# what is best way to read one file and check that content is present in other file

Tags: java

I have two files in different folder like inputfolder1 and inputfolder2 ,Now i need to check if  inputfolder1 file content is present in inputfolder2 file if no then create new output file.

```
public class CompareContent {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    String path="";
    Path filePath = Paths.get(path+"inputfolder1", "data.txt");

    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines( filePath )) 
    {

        lines.forEach(p->{

            System.out.println(p);
            try {
                boolean flag=FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(path+"inputfolder2\\data2.txt")).contains(p);
              System.out.println(flag);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        });


    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. Please limit your question to a  [minimal, complete and verifyable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: To answer your question, you have to read both files and compare the content.

Comment: Hi, please try doing this yourself and then if you are unable, post the code you tried and any errors you have encountered.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc, "best" way would also keep the app from running out of memory and many more. Way out of scope for simple SO question.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use the File I/O package like this:

To verify if a file exists:

```
boolean fileExists = java.nio.file.File.exists( Paths.get( "inputfolder1/"+ fileName ));
```

To verify if there's content, you can use Path.size(), which will return the size of the file:

```
int fileSize = Path.size( Paths.get( "inputfolder1/" + fileName ));
```

You may find it useful to read:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/check.html

and

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

In general, check out the full File I/O tutorial:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html

In general it is expected from you to include some already tried code so you can receive some code feedback also.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Dumb question:So my suggestion, the answer,  is to use the File I/O package, and the links are the references?

Comment: You are (at least partially) right. But using the File I/O package is does not tell the OP how to solve his specific problem.